# BMW E30 coupe rear side window frame

Tags: bmw, body

How can I put the rear side window's lower frame back on?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the chrome piece, if so there are clips that must hold on to frame. If the clips were damaged, you might need to replace them. Can you show a picture of the bottom, as its been a while since I replaced one of them.

Comment: Yes, I just looked through the service manual (page 51-216 (body equipment > window recess cover strip, outside — remove and install)), there should be nothing special. Just pry it off to remove, then check for and replace any damaged clips, and pop it back in to install.